# Keeping TextArea Formatting

Tags: java, gwt

When sending the contents of a `TextArea` which contains formatted text to the server for storage, the formatting of that text is lost. The text in question contains word wraps and other formatting characters, all of which were lost when the text was sent to the server for storage.

The content of the `TextArea` was:

> Hello World,
>
> I am test message.
>
> Regards, test message # 1

And this is what went to the server:

> Hello World, I am test message.Regards, test message # 1

Is it possible to keep the formatting exactly as it is displayed by the TextArea?

Comment: How do you know that formatting is gone? You trying to display it in server logs, or in some Label on the page?

Comment: I am trying to use GWT HTML object as setHTML(message); to see message back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word wrapping is not part of the text, it's visual and it depends on the widget that displays the text.

**Word wrap does not really add new lines to the text.**

The only formatting you can have in TextArea is line feeds.
TextArea does not have setHtml/getHtml methods bacause it can't handle HTML.

The widget below does support HTML:

**com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RichTextArea**

Hope that helps.